# Painting Recognition App (possibly for mobile devices too)

Tags: mobile, image-recognition

I'm trying to design an application for painting recognition for pictures taken from the mobile phone.

If it could run on mobile devices it would be cool, but it's ok even if it's only for desktop (and I just feed it with the pics taken from the smartphone).

So far, the only app that I found for this is [Artbit](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.vstory.artbit&hl=en?utm_source=homepage) but it crashes on my Nexus 5.

Githubs projects are fine (better if linked to some paper, so I can cite it in mine).

Sorry if this is a bad question but this is the first question that I ask here.

Answer (score 1):

If a hosted service is ok, then try https://cloud.google.com/vision/

Google Cloud Vision API enables developers to understand the content of an image by encapsulating powerful machine learning models in an easy to use REST API. It quickly classifies images into thousands of categories (e.g., "sailboat", "lion", "Eiffel Tower"), detects individual objects and faces within images, and finds and reads printed words contained within images.

Comment: I'm sorry but rather than giving an input image containing a painting and return "there is a paint here" I want "here there is the mona Lisa" or "here there is the scream by van Gogh" (and of course it must work for less famous paintings too). Do u believe it works anyway?

Comment: I think neither Google Cloud vision or the competition from Microsoft can do this out of the box. You would need to find a network that can be trained - but this requires you to have 1000s of images of the paintings that you want to detect.

Comment: Well that's the point of my question, I was asking if there is an app which is already trained for recognizing thousands of paintings. Something like this: https://www.recognize.im/site/showcaseApps but I can't understand how to download it